# Prevent new cmd window from closing

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, exe

My questions are: How can I prevent a program that I execute in the cmd from opening and closing a second cmd window without changing the original source code? (I only have the .exe file) And: Is there a way to make the program print the output in the same cmd window, instead of opening a second one?

I'm using Windows 11 and executing a program (.exe file) in the cmd. This program opens a second cmd window, prints some stuff and then immediately closes. I'm not the owner of the program, so I don't have a way to change the source code thereof and make it so that it pauses the cmd window after it is done executing. I saw responses to similar questions where people suggested adding /k at the end of the code in the cmd prompt to prevent it from closing but the problem is that the program opens a second cmd window and the /k command doesn't apply to it so it doesn't work.

Comment: Give `Start-Process path\to\executable.exe -NoNewWindow` a try in PowerShell

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried  `start-process -FilePath "C:\...\my_file.exe" -NoNewWindow` and it still opened a new window

Comment: Why not tell us what the program is, and/or provide us with a link. Just because something has an .exe extension, it doesn't mean it cannot be investigated or its behavior changed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Compo I cannot provide you the program, it's confidential. The point is that it calculates stuff, prints the results in the cmd and then closes itself. I resolved my problem because I found out it also creates a log.txt file which I can access and read, however, that is not the point of the question. I think my question is pretty clear - executing .exe file from cmd opens a 2nd cmd window, prints results and closes itself. Is there a way to prevent this? So far, the things I've tried haven't worked out.

Comment: @Hikikomori, if your executable runs a console window and you don't want to make changes to that executable, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your program *explicitly* creates a *new console window*.

Therefore, none of the regular invocation mechanisms (direct invocation, invocation via `Start-Process`) will make a difference.

You have two fundamental options:

- Check if the target executable has some *configuration mechanism* that would cause it to keep the explicitly created console window open *until the user decides to close it*, such as via a command-line option or environment variable.
- If not - and assuming that `cmd.exe` is used to launch the new console window - you **can create a *proxy* executable for `cmd.exe` that keeps the window open until the user presses a key** - see below.

  - Note: In principle, the technique can also be applied to other executables , as long as you know the program's executable name and as long as it isn't invoked with a *fixed path* (even then, conceivably, you could *temporarily* replace it, but that is obviously a suboptimal solution).

---

To use a proxy executable for `cmd.exe`:

- From *Windows PowerShell*, compile the proxy `cmd.exe` executable, as shown below.
- Assuming that the proxy `cmd.exe` was created in the *current* directory (adjust as needed):

  ```
  $prevPath = $env:PATH; $prevComSpec = $env:ComSpec

  # *Temporarily* replace cmd.exe with the proxy program.
  $env:ComSpec = Convert-Path .\cmd.exe
  $env:Path = (Split-Path -Parent $env:ComSpec) + ';' + $env:PATH

  # Now invoke your program - synchronously
  Start-Process -Wait yourProgram.exe 

  # Restore the original environment.
  $env:Path = $prevPath
  $env:ComSpec = $prevComSpec
  ```

**Compile the proxy `cmd.exe` executable**:

Note: Must be run in *Windows PowerShell* (creating `.exe` files from [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) isn't supported as of this writing (PowerShell 7.3.x) - see [GitHub issue #13344](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13344)).

```
# Create a proxy for `cmd.exe` in the current directory
# that invokes the real `cmd.exe` behind the scenes and
# then waits for the user to press a key before exiting,
# which keeps the console window open.
Add-Type -OutputAssembly .\cmd.exe @'
  using System;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
  using System.Diagnostics;

  static class Program
  {
    static int Main()
    {
      // Get cmd.exe's full path.
      var cmdExePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe");
      // Strip this exe's own name/path from the original command line.
      var passThruArgs = Regex.Replace(Environment.CommandLine, @"^.+\.exe""? ", "");
      // Synchronously run cmd.exe with the pass-through arguments
      var psi = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = cmdExePath,
        Arguments = passThruArgs,
        UseShellExecute = false
      };
      var ps = Process.Start(psi);
      ps.WaitForExit();
      // Prompt for a keypress to prevent the window from closing.
      Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
      Console.ReadKey(true);
      // Pass cmd.exe's exit code through.
      return ps.ExitCode;
    }
  }
'@
```